# Load cache manifest file

Tags: html, iis, caching, content-type

How to make server to return manifest file with `text/cache-manifest` content type? By default, if I put it to the server and include into `<html manifest="cache.manifest">` it is being loaded with type `application/x-ms-manifest`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's one of the reasons why the recommended extension for manifest files is now `.appcache` - Microsoft is already using `.manifest` for something else.  To configure content types:

- In IIS6 and below, add the MIME type mappings on the header tab of your virtual directory or web site properties ([MS instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true)).
- In IIS7 and later, either go to [MIME types in Features view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx) or [add a `mimeMap` entry under `staticContent` in your web.config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx) like `<mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />`

Comment: One thing to note. I had a .manifest file and just changed the extension to .appcache in Visual Studio. This didn't work and it was only when I created a completely new text file called cache.appcache that I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you may include

`AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache`

in your .htaccess

or if you happen to use PHP you can send header information

```
header('Content-Type: text/cache-manifest');
```

Comment: You don't get an `.htaccess` on IIS

Answer (score 0):

Was having trouble caching an offline site on the iPad through GoDaddy hosting... Their mime type is incorrect for Safari support, so I simply made an cache.ASPX page:

```
<%@Page ContentType="text/cache-manifest" ResponseEncoding ="utf-8" %>
```

At the bottom of the page... Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a helicon file type .htaccess for it to work with IIS. Is can have an .htaccess file, just needs to be a # Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file

## Version 3.1.0.82